# Google Sheet IMPORTXML div class (class within class) with specific div number

Tags: html, google-sheets

=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5797?category=", "//div[contains(@class, card-body)]")

The code above manages to scrape the data from all the div with class card-body. However, I just want to scrape the specific rolls of div to google sheet, for example, 1-3 but IMPORTXML only allows up to 2 arguments. How should I do to achieve the result that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

card-body should be inside quotes
you can try this

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5797?category=AR","//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")
```

to limit n number of rows you can use query function

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML(A1, B1)),"select * limit 4",-1)
```

`OR`

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5797?category=AR", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select * limit 4",-1)
```

Comment: Bravo, thanks a lot for helping me. This is the answer that I demanded. 

I have another additional question if I want to match a certain word based on the results from the query,  I try the code below but somehow it prompts out an error state "MATCH range must be a single row or a single column.", how should I edit it to make it work? 


=MATCH("*Quarterly*", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5797?category=", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select * limit 3"), 0)

Comment: You can change Select * to select Col1 like:

=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5797?category=AR", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select Col1 limit 4",-1)

Comment: Successfully work! Appreciate your extra effort a lot ^^